# Generate new column with randomly assigned dummies

Tags: stata

I have a column called "DATA" in my Stata dataset that shows different types of ID based on which city a company is located.

What I would like to do is to generate a new column with dummy variables 0 and 1. The dummy should be randomly assigned over the columns with ID. 50 % should be 1 and 50 % should be 0 and the specific ID doesn't matter as it is random.

I've tried with different commands and I guess it should look something like this:

generate Dummy = (DATA =  )

I did try different types of command and searched both Stata and Youtube tutorials without success.

Comment: Data example please showing the kind of data you have and the kind of result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what this means is that you want a single dummy variable ("column" is spreadsheet-speak) that is 1 for about 50% of identifiers and 0 for the other roughly 50% of identifiers, chosen randomly. (That is, you don't want dummy variables, plural.)

If so, the twist is that all observations for each identifier are to be selected, or not selected, so just getting a random choice with 0 or 1 equally likely is not good enough.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float id
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
end

set seed 314159265 
bysort id : gen wanted = runiformint(0, 1) if _n == 1 
by id: replace wanted = wanted[1]

list, sepby(id)

     +-------------+
     | id   wanted |
     |-------------|
  1. |  1        1 |
  2. |  1        1 |
  3. |  1        1 |
     |-------------|
  4. |  2        1 |
  5. |  2        1 |
  6. |  2        1 |
     |-------------|
  7. |  3        0 |
  8. |  3        0 |
  9. |  3        0 |
     |-------------|
 10. |  4        0 |
 11. |  4        0 |
 12. |  4        0 |
     +-------------+
```

We can't comment on code that didn't work if you don't show it.